# Use of を with 進める

Tags: grammar, particle-を, relative-clauses

> 2020年の開業に向けて、ＪＲ東日本が東京の山手線の品川駅と田町駅の間で**建設を進めている新しい駅の工事現場**が、初めて報道関係者に公開されました。
>   The construction site of a new station, that JR are progressing between the Yamanote and Tamachi stations with the aim of a 2020 completion, was opened to the press for the first time.

I'm struggling with the part in bold. If I'm parsing this correctly then the simplified relative clause will be

> ＪＲ東日本が建設を進めている駅

My problem is that 進める already has a subject (ＪＲ東日本) and an object (建設), but I thought 駅 would be the object.

My only guess is that を isn't the object marker here but means 'through' (like the use with 歩く for example). So the clause would read 'the station that JR are progressing through *the* construction *phase*.

Am I correct or have I made a serious parsing error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

駅 is connected to 建設.  「駅の建設」というふうにつながります。

The non-relative version of

> 「JR東日本が（東京の山手線の品川駅と田町駅の間で）建設を進めている**（新しい）駅**」

is...

> 「JR東日本が（東京の山手線の品川駅と田町駅の間で）**（新しい）駅**の建設を進めている。」

Comment: Hmm, so you can promote part of an object to the head noun position? I didn't know that before.

Comment: うわっ、回答してはったんや。ワシの消そかな・・

Comment: ええっ、消さんといてんかーーー

Answer (score 2):

It seems you might be overthinking here.

First of all, 「進{すす}める」 is a 100% genuine ***transitive*** verb, which is why it naturally takes 「を」.

The 「を」 that you are talking about can only be used with ***intransitive*** verbs.  (「町{まち}を歩{ある}く」、「公園{こうえん}を走{はし}る」, etc.)  So, 「進める」 cannot be used with that particular 「を」.

「建設{けんせつ}を進める」, therefore, means "***to proceed with construction***".  (It is frustrating having to use the English intransitive verb "to proceed" to define the Japanese transitive verb.)

> My problem is that 進める already has a subject (ＪＲ東日本) and an object (建設), but I thought 駅 would be the object.

「建設」 is the object.  They are ***not*** 進めている an 駅{えき}.  One could, of course, say that they are 進めている the 駅の建設.

> 建設を進めている新しい駅の工事現場{こうじげんば}

thus means:

> "the construction site for the new station that (JR) has proceeded to build"

The original contains both 建設 and 工事.  In my attempt not to use "construction" twice, I ended up using "proceeded to build"

Answer (score 1):

> My problem is that 進める already has a subject (ＪＲ東日本) and an object (建設), but I thought 駅 would be the object.

Japanese sentences can have more than one "subject". The un-relativized, base sentence is something like this.

> この新しい駅**は**JR東日本**が**建設**を**進めている。
>   As for this new station, JR East is proceeding with the construction.

Similar examples:

> - 彼が中国で計画を進めているプロジェクト
> - 彼女がすでに内容を確認してある書類
> - 彼が品種を改良しているバラ

Answer (score 0):

駅 is part of the object.

ＪＲが駅の建設を進めている。
JR is advancing the construction of a station

ＪＲが建設を進めている駅。
The station whose construction JR is advancing